# POST parameters missing after AJAX update to form

Tags: php, ajax, forms, prototypejs

I have an app built using PHP & Prototype JS.  I have two chained select boxes which form part of a bigger form.  When a user changes the value in the first select box a Prototype Ajax Updater request is fired of to get a list of values to display in the second select box:

```
landlordId = $F('landlord_id');
branchId = $F('branch_id');
new Ajax.Updater('landlord_branches_div', baseUrl+"/landlord/getLandlordBranches", {
    method:'post', postBody:'landlord_id='+landlordId +'&branch_id='+ branchId,
});
```

This returns a HTML block populated into the second select box e.g (can even see this is what is returned via Firebug):

```
<select name="branch_id" id="branch_id" >
    <option value="all" selected="selected">All Branches</option>
    <option value="99" selected>HORDEN</option>
</select>
```

However when the form is then submitted (via a regular form submit) after the ajax request above, branch_id (as set in the second select box) is missing from the post.  It is present in the post OK if the initial page loaded is just submitted without triggering any ajax update on the second select box.

The ironic thing about this is that it is working OK in IE but doesn't work in Chrome or Firefox for example.

Would appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    landlordId = $F('landlord_id');
branchId = $F('branch_id');
new Ajax.Updater('landlord_branches_div', baseUrl+"/landlord/getLandlordBranches", {
    method:'post',
    parameters:{ landlord_id: landlordId, branch_id: branchId}
});
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk.  Maybe I didn't explain the problem correctly, the ajax updater is correctly returning the right HTML to replace within the div i.e. the select block above, however it's when I subsequently post the form that branch_id doesn't form part of the post, even through it does if I just post the form without changing anything.  It's as if the post can't read the updated html even though I can see it is correct on the page via Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't get it wrong, so you have 2 select boxes there, the second select boxes options will be filled by an ajax updater, right? try this :

Here is the html structure (yours may differ from this):

```
<form id="form_id">
   <div id="landlord_div">
       <select id="landlord_id" name="landlord_id" onchange="ajaxcall()">
           <option value=1></option>
           <option value=2></option>
       </select>
   </div>
   <div id="landlord_branches_div">
   </div>
</form>
```

Just make sure your elements is under the Form element.
The next is the ajax updater script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxcall = function() {
       new Ajax.updater('landlord_branches_div', 'your_ajax_url', {
            method:'post',
            parameters:'landlord_id='+$F('landlord_id'),
       });
    }
</script>
```

Since this ajax call is used to show the second select box (the branch selector), you don't need to post the branch_id there. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks - managed to find another work around but it involved a page reload.  When I get a few mins I'll try your fix to see if it helps.